# How to get Members object type of Synced Active Directory Group

Tags: .net, active-directory

Hi I am able to Sync/Search Active Directory Group. But don't how to get the object type of its members, because directory search result return just members name.

Comment: How did you search your members? In another post, you seems to be using a wrong way. You can always tell the DirectorySearcher to include the ObjectClass and ObjectCategory attributes when doing the search.

Comment: Thanx harvey, I think you are telling about directive searcher filter, and I am doing that

Answer (score 0):

The AD group will only contain the DN (distinguished name) of its members - nothing else. There's no "magic way" to get the types, too.

If you really have to, you will need to bind to each member that's been returned from enumerating the group, and then determine its type when it's bound. No other way I'm afraid...